# I am trying to write a program that turns the input into capital lettering

Tags: c++

Here is my program

```
//fileio.cpp -- basic file i/o
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>          //some compilers include fstream in iostream but VC++ does not
#include <string>           //our first look at the C++ string object
#include <algorithm>        //presume str is a string type variable you want to convert to uppercase
using namespace std;
bool openfile(fstream& f, const char* fname, ios_base::fmtflags flags);
int main()
{
    const char* fname = "myfile";   //or string fname ("str.txt") in C++11
    string input;                       //our first look at the C++ string object
    fstream myfile;                     //construct fstream object for file i/o
    openfile(myfile, fname, ios_base::out); //open file for output (current contents lost)
    std::transform(myfile.begin(), myfile.end(), myfile.begin(), ::toupper);
    while (cout << "Enter a line ('q' to quit): " && getline(cin, input))
    {
        if (input == "q")
            break;
        else                            //exit while loop
            myfile << input << endl;    //pipe string we read file add new line character
    }
    myfile.close();                     //close our file
    openfile(myfile, fname, ios_base::in);  //reopen it for input
    std::transform(myfile.begin(), myfile.end(), myfile.begin(), ::toupper);
    cout << "\nHere's whats in " << fname << ":\n";
    while (getline(myfile, input))      //get and print all the lines
        cout << input << endl;
    system("pause");
}
//function to open based on name and i/o flags
bool openfile(fstream & f, const char* fname, ios_base::fmtflags flags)
{
    f.open(fname, flags);
    if (f.is_open())
        return true;
    else
    {
        cerr << "Unexpected error trying to open " << 
fname << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I may be missing something simple but I am getting several errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" has no member "begin"  fileio2 C:\Users\burnsk\source\repos\Hello\fileio2\fileio2.cpp  14  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0109   expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type fileio2 C:\Users\burnsk\source\repos\Hello\fileio2\fileio2.cpp  14  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" has no member "begin"  fileio2 C:\Users\burnsk\source\repos\Hello\fileio2\fileio2.cpp  14  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" has no member "begin"  fileio2 C:\Users\burnsk\source\repos\Hello\fileio2\fileio2.cpp  24  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
```

Here are the errors.

Comment: `std::transform(myfile.begin(), myfile.end(), myfile.begin(), ::toupper);` -- This does not turn a file's contents into upper case.

Comment: Streams don't have `begin()` or `end()` methods.  You'll need to use a stream iterator instead.  See [`istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

Comment: Try to read and understand the error message. You need the part where `"std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" has no member "begin"`.  Also I suggest you to reduce the amount of code in your example to the minimum. It is time consuming to read the whole your program